# JSF h:commandButton is not working inside h:DataTable

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I'm trying to delete a specific data in a table, i try to get the column id  by using commandButton but it doesn't work, i tried to just show a message in the console when the button is clicked but no luck at all, i tried also some solutions that were offered in this community but it didn't work for me.
Ps: i tried to use ViewScoped instead of request, but it didnt work too.
**Here is a part of my code:**

```
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton
            value="Afficher les demandes"
            action="#{demandeBean1.listedemandes}"
            styleClass="btn btn-success" />
    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable
            value="#{demandeBean1.demandes}"
            var="demande"
            styleClass="table table-bordered"
            cellspacing="4"
            width="60%"
            rowClasses="paire,impaire"
            headerClass="titre">

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Date de demande" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{demande.dateDmd}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Date de debut" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{demande.dateDbtAbs}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Date de fin" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{demande.dateFinAbs}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Nombre de jours" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{demande.nbrJr}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Type" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{demande.type}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Status" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{demande.status}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Action" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:commandButton
                    value="Supprimer"
                    styleClass="btn btn-danger"
                    actionListener="#{demandeBean1.supprimer(demande.idDmd)}">
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

**My Bean**:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DemandeBean implements Serializable {

    private int idDmd;
    private Date dateDbtAbs;
    private Date dateDmd;
    private Date dateFinAbs;
    private int nbrJr;
    private String status;
    private String type;
    private List<Demande> demandes;

    public DemandeBean() {}

    public void supprimer(int id) {
        System.out.println("It works"); //this is not displaying
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a getter for `idDmd`?

Comment: Yes i have setters and getters for every variable i just didn't write them here that's all

Comment: Ps: listeDemande is a function its defined, i didnt include it here because my code works the data get displayed the only problem i have is the Button not working inside the DataTable.